# How can I update a range within an array with a sequence

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Given an array of values, how can I update a range with a sequence within that array, efficiently?
Updates are performed multiple times. After all updates are performed, we can query any index of the array for its final value.

If we update a value of `v` at index `i`, every element at index `j` is increased with a value of 
`max { v - | i - j | ,  0 }`

For example.

```
array = {1,1,1,1,1,1}
```

Now I do an update at index *4* with a value of *3* the resulting array will look like this:

```
array = {1,1,2,3,4,3}
```

I want to perform both operations efficiently.

Comment: `array = {1,1,2,3,4,3}` You forgot to explain why.

Comment: Seems like you skipped a few steps in the example.

Comment: "Every element at index j"? There is only one element at index j. Do you mean "every element beyond index i"? And I don't understand how, if you put 3 at index 4, that changes the value at index 3. You need to explain your problem a little better.

Comment: As everybody said, please explain the problem a little better. May be add a few examples and how you arrive at the answer. Also please add whatever code you gave written to give us a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can't update a range of elements "efficiently".  Questions like these are always about figuring out how to avoid updating a range of elements altogether.

To figure out this one, consider two operations:

- `INTEGRATE(A)` takes an array and replaces every element `A[i]` with `sum(A[0]...A[i])`.
- `DIFF(A)` takes an array and replaces every element with its difference from the previous element (the first element is left unaltered).

These operations have some important properties:

- They are inverses: `INTEGRATE(DIFF(A))` = `DIFF(INTEGRATE(A))` = `A` for all arrays `A`; and
- They are linear:  If `A` = `B`+`C`, then `INTEGATE(A)` = `INTEGRATE(B)` + `INTEGRATE(C)`, and similarly for `DIFF`.

Your final array is the sum of the original array, plus a whole bunch of those "triangle" arrays.  Let's say it's `A + T1 + T2 + T3...` etc.

Each one of those triangles has a whole bunch of non-zero elements, but watch what happens when you apply `DIFF` twice:

`[0,0,1,2,3,2,1,0,0]` -> `[0,0,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,0]` -> `[0,0,1,0,0,-2,0,0,1]`

The result has only **3** non-zero elements. That gives us a way to calculate your final array quickly.

Let `D(X)` = `DIFF(DIFF(X))` and let `I(X)` = `INTEGRATE(INTEGRATE(X))`.  Then instead of calculating `A + T1 + T2 + T3...`, you calculate `I( D(A) + D(T1) + D(T2) + D(T3)... )`

Since all those `D(Tx)` have at most 3 non-zero elements, it's quick and easy to add them into the result.

Comment: This makes updates efficient, but not lookups.  Because to lookup you have to scan the whole array.

Comment: @btilly  The question says that all the queries are at the end, so you calculate the result array in linear time (including the integration), and then just get the requested element for each query.

Comment: Ah.  You're right..  Normally with these I'd expect the two types of requests to be interleaved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm deliberately explaining how to solve it, without giving you full code. This also handles the complex case of interleaved updates and lookups, but therefore is more complex than what Matter Timmermans came up with.

You obviously can't use an array as your representation.  It makes lookups fast, but an update with value `k` will be an `O(k)` operation.

Our second try, is to just have a list of the updates.  Now updates are `O(1)`, but after `m` updates a lookup is `O(m)`.

What we need is to have a way to store updates such that both adding an update and doing a lookup are fast.

The first step is to change an update from "update at a value" to "update a range by a linear rule".  That is currently you say:

```
update at 4 by 3
```

Instead we'd say:

```
from 2 to 3:
    update by x - 2
from 4 to 5:
    update by 7 - x
```

This isn't yet a win.  But it becomes one when you rewrite the ranges in terms of a standard set of intervals.  First the original array

```
from 0 to 5 1 + 0x
```

Now the array after update:

```
from 0 to 5, 1 + 0x +
    from 2 to 3, -1 + x
    from 4 to 5, 7 - x
```

This can be represented compactly in 2 arrays:

```
m = [0, 0,  1, 0, -1, 0]
b = [1, 0, -1, 0,  7, 0]
```

And as complicated as it feels, now both updates and lookups wind up with `O(log(n))` work.

For example for a lookup:

```
def rising_binary (n):
    power = 1
    m = 0
    yield m
    while m < n:
        if n & power:
            m += power
            yield m
        power *= 2

...

answer = 0
for bin in rising_binary(k):
    answer += m[bin] * k + b[bin]
```